# VoiceOver behavior is inconsistent on dropdown select options

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, screen-readers

I am currently working on the VoiceOver experience for a custom web component and I have come across an inconsistency in the VoiceOver behavior.

My custom web component functions as a dropdown select with options to choose from. In the below scenarios, I describe the varying behavior of VoiceOver. Thanks in advance for reading this.

**Scenario 1:**

The dropdown has 3 available options to choose from: Option 1, Option 2, Option 3

```
<custom-select label="Dropdown Label">
    <custom-option value="Option 1">Option 1</custom-option>
    <custom-option value="Option 2">Option 2</custom-option>
    <custom-option value="Option 3">Option 3</custom-option>
</custom-select>
```

You select Option 2. This closes the pop-up and updates the dropdown component to display the option you've chosen

You then re-open the dropdown, focus jumps to the previously selected option (in this case Option 2, which now has a checkmark next to it), and VoiceOver says:

*Checkmark. Option 2. Clickable. You are currently on a text element.*

This is the VoiceOver behavior you will consistently get for any option that is not the *last* option in the list. The next scenario explains what happens there...

**Scenario 2:**

Again, 3 available options to choose from: Option 1, Option 2, Option 3

You select the last option, Option 3. This closes the pop-up and updates the dropdown component to display the option you've chosen

You then re-open the dropdown, focus jumps to the previously selected option (the checkmarked Option 3), and VoiceOver says:

*Option 1. Option 2. Checkmark. Option 3. Clickable. You are currently on a text element.*

So only when you choose the ***last*** option, the VoiceOver decides to read ***all*** of the options before getting to the one that has focus...

**Relevant HTML:**

The parent component contains a button which toggles a display div containing the dropdown options (the "slot" for nested components). I've stripped it down to the relevant attributes, classes and directives for presentation's sake (written in Svelte.js):

```
<button
    type="button"
    aria-required={ariaRequired}
    aria-haspopup="listbox"
    aria-label={ariaLabel}
    aria-disabled={ariaDisabled}
    aria-expanded={ariaExpanded}
    on:click={toggleOptions}>
    {display}
</button>
<div
    tabindex="-1"
    class:hidden={optionSelectVisable === false}>
    <slot />
</div>
```

And then a nested, option component looks like this:

```
<div
    on:click={dispatchOption}
    role="option"
    value={value}
    id="option-{inputID}"
    aria-selected={ariaSelected}
    aria-disabled={ariaDisabled}
    tabindex={tabindex}>
    <div>
        <custom-icon
            type="checkmark"
            aria-label="checkmark"
            class:hidden={displayCheckmark === false}/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <slot />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Rendered HTML (example w/ Option 1 checked):**

```
<custom-select label="Dropdown Label">
    →#shadow-root
    <custom-option value="Option 1">
        ↓#shadow-root
        <div
            role="option"
            aria-selected="true"
            aria-disabled="false"
            value="Option 1"
            tabindex="0">...</div>
        "Option 1"
    <custom-option>
    <custom-option value="Option 2">
        ↓#shadow-root
        <div
            role="option"
            aria-selected="false"
            aria-disabled="false"
            value="Option 2"
            tabindex="0">...</div>
        "Option 2"
    <custom-option>
    <custom-option value="Option 3">
        ↓#shadow-root
        <div
            role="option"
            aria-selected="false"
            aria-disabled="false"
            value="Option 3"
            tabindex="0">...</div>
        "Option 3"
    <custom-option>
</custom-select>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your rendered html as well? That's what the screenreader will see.

Comment: Updated to include rendered HTML. Thank you

Comment: Any reason you're not using select controls for this?